# Validate checkbox messages in Parsley.js

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I'm using Parsley.js to validate a group of checkboxes. My problem is that I want the error message to appear only after the last checkbox, not after the first one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, depending upon how you want things to work, you have a couple of options.

Did you mean that you want the messages for all the checkboxes to display in the same place, after the last one? If so, you can put all of the error message fields after the last checkbox. Use the `parsley-error-container` option on each of the checkbox fields to do this. You may have to create your own target span to hold the message.

Did you mean you want the validation on the checkboxes to only kick in after the user leaves the last checkbox? This is much trickier, but I can suggest a solution if this is what you want.